# Port Forwarding with 2 NICs via Windows 7 firewall

Tags: windows-7, networking, firewall, port-forwarding

I have a computer with two network cards, each of them connected to a separate network. I would like to forward all requests that arrive via port X from one networks to port Y on a host in the other network.

Is this something I can realize with the Windows 7 firewall and if yes, what would a configuration like this look typicially look like?

Thanks!

Comment: Great, question answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Port Forwarding with 2 NICs via Windows 7 firewall

This can done using `netsh`.

---

#### To add forwarding

> ```
> netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=4422 listenaddress=192.168.1.111 connectport=80 connectaddress=192.168.0.33
> ```

---

#### To remove forwarding

> ```
> netsh interface portproxy delete v4tov4 listenport=4422 listenaddress=192.168.1.111
> ```

Source Stack Overflow answer [port forwarding in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11535395/3536342) by [user1256477](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256477/user1256477)

---

#### Further reading

- [NETSH (Network Shell)](http://ss64.com/nt/netsh.html) - Configure Network Interfaces, Windows Firewall, Routing & remote access.